# Wordpress getting list of child categories of a specific category

Tags: php, wordpress

I need to get the list of child categories of a specific parent category.

I have used:

```
wp_list_categories()
```

But it outputted not what I wanted. It just outputted the first parent category without any siblings/children.

I also tried `get_categories()` which outputted an object.

Scenario:

I have `ParentCategory1` Which has 10 `childCategory`.

Now I want to get the list of these children using for example:

```
 wp_get_cats(array("parent"=>"ParentCategory1"));
```

Answer (score 4):

You need to use arguments to get the result you want from a function like wp_list_categories.

Below is what I consider to be the optimal parameters for your needs. Make sure to specify the parent category ID in 'child_of'.

```
wp_list_categories( array(
    'hide_empty' => 0, // show empty categories in the list
    'child_of' => enter-ID-here // Replace with the ID of the parent category
) );
```

I'm guessing you only saw one category before because your other categories were empty.

Further reading on `wp_list_categories`: http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories

UPDATE:

In your scenario you refer to ParentCategory1. Using my example above you would find out the ID of ParentCategory1 (integer) and use that.